# Count returns 0 for a column that exists

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have a MySQL table that contains 2 fields - deviceID and jobID. Below is a sample of what the table looks like with Data in it:

```
+----------------------+----------------------+
|      deviceID        |        jobID         |
+----------------------+----------------------+
| f18204efba03a874bb9f | be83dec5d120c42a6b94 |
| 49ed54279fb983317051 | be83dec5d120c42a6b94 |
+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Usually i run a query that looks a little like this:

```
SELECT Count(deviceID)
FROM pendingCollect
WHERE jobID=%s AND deviceID=%s
```

Now this runs fine and usually returns a 0 if the device doesnt exist with the specified job, and 1 if it does - which is perfectly fine. HOWEVER, for some reason - im having problems with thew second row. The query:

```
SELECT Count(deviceID)
FROM pendingCollect
WHERE jobID='be83dec5d120c42a6b94' AND deviceID='49ed54279fb983317051'
```

is returning 0 for some reason - Even though the data exists in the table3 and the count should be returned as 1, it is returning as 0... Any ideas why this is?

thanks in Advance

EDIT:
Sorry for the type guys! The example SQL query shouldnt have had the same devID and jobID.. My Mistake

EDIT 2:
Some people are suggesting i use the SQL LIKE operator.... Is there a need for this? Again, when i run the following query, everything runs fine and returns 1. It only seems to be on the deviceID "49ed54279fb983317051" that is returning the error...

```
SELECT Count(deviceID)
FROM pendingCollect
WHERE jobID='be83dec5d120c42a6b94' AND deviceID='f18204efba03a874bb9f'
```

The above query works as expected returning 1

Comment: your `jobid` is the same as `device` id in the query, i think you didn´t change the number

Comment: Do you mean jobid and deviceid to be the same in your query...?

Comment: Nope, sorryt about that ! Check the edit in the OP :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the correct value for jobID. Presently you are providing the value of deviceID in jobID which is not matching and hence returing 0 rows.

```
SELECT Count(deviceID) FROM pendingCollect 
WHERE jobID='49ed54279fb983317051' AND deviceID='49ed54279fb983317051'
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The reason why

```
jobID=%s and deviceID=%s
```

which I think you mean

```
jobID like '%s' and deviceID like '%s'
```

was working because both were matching. But now since  you are using the AND condition and providing jobID value same for both so it would not match any row. And will return 0 rows.

**EDIT:**

You query seems to be correct and is giving giving the correct result.

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5cb2/1)**

You need to check if there is any space which is getting added to the values for the jobID and deviceID column.

Comment: Although i didnt downvote -  I can tell you thats not the solution - I made a Typo in the OP - the jobID and devID will never be the same

Comment: @amartin94:- What is the datatype for the two columns?

Comment: @amartin94:- I have updated my answer. Yuo query looks good and is working as expected. You need to check if there is any space which is getting added to the values of jobID or deviceID while inserting them.

Comment: @amartin94:- Check if there is any space which present in `49ed54279fb983317051` value?

Comment: No space in the DB Field tat contains that devID .... Inserting just the string with no spacing

Comment: @amartin94:- Can you try this: `SELECT Count(deviceID)
FROM pendingCollect
WHERE TRIM(jobID)='be83dec5d120c42a6b94' AND TRIM(deviceID)='49ed54279fb983317051'`

Comment: After reinserting the Data to the table and using your Query it seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the `AND` operator. `AND` means both conditions must be true. Instead of `AND`, use `OR` operator.

```
SELECT Count(deviceID)
FROM pendingCollect
WHERE jobID = '49ed54279fb983317051' OR deviceID = '49ed54279fb983317051'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the real value the column contains, there might be some unprintable character in it:

```
SELECT deviceID, hex(deviceID), hex('49ed54279fb983317051')
FROM pendingCollect
WHERE jobID='be83dec5d120c42a6b94';
```

If there is anything weird in that deviceID, it should show as a difference in the hex output - for the value you want, I did not add it to the where condition as you have problems "targeting" it, so this query will return rows even for the other devices with the same jobID.